# Android RecyclerView Persistent Images after Async Download

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, android-recyclerview

**a little background...**

I have an app, designed using MVP, that displays Images and Text as a card inside of a `RecyclerView`.  On the opening of the app API information is pulled, which includes the Image download URL.  Inside my `<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> Adapter`.  I execute an `AsyncTask`  to download the image for each card when it is created, each image download(or card) has its own thread.  While the download is in progress an empty grey square is shown as a placeholder. All of this works as intended but...

**the problem is...**

While all of this works I have noticed that when I scroll up (or down) and new card views are being created the images are downloading again.  Is it possible that once the images are downloaded they do not need to be downloaded again when the same card (or its index) is recreated.  This can be seen in *Play Newsstand* and *Instagram* apps, or any app that contains a list of images.

So how can I accomplish this in my app?

**possible solutions...**

I) Download all of the images (instead of just the URLs) before and during the time the `RecyclerView` is being created using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and pass those into our `<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> Adapter`.

II) Use the *ViewHolder* pattern. When binding the `ImageView` inside of my adapter it would reference an object in the presenter/model layer which would provide a stored image or download one if there is not an image available.

III) Add some sort of logic prior to binding such as

```
if(image has already been download) {
    getDownloadedImage()
} else {
    downloadNewImage()
}
```

Any advice or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if you need more information or code.

**the code...**

NewsAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case IMAGE_LAYOUT:
            ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
            initViewholderImage(imageViewHolder, position);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

private void initViewholderImage(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleText.setText(articleList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.abstractText.setText(articleList.get(position).getAbstract());
    holder.globalText.setText(articleList.get(position).getGeoFacet().get(0));

    try {
//this is where we are downloading our image in a background thread
     ImageDownload imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
        imageDownloader.imageDownload(articleList.get(position).getMultimedia().get(3).getUrl(),
                holder.articleImage);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ImageDownloader

```
public class ImageDownloader {
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

public ImageDownloader() {

}

public void imageDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {

    if(cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {
        BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask asyncTask = new BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask(imageView);
        DownloadDrawable downloadDrawable = new DownloadDrawable(asyncTask);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadDrawable);
        asyncTask.execute(url);
    }
}

private static BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof DownloadDrawable) {
            DownloadDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadDrawable)drawable;
            return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloadTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
        String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
        if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
            bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same URL is already being downloaded.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

class BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> weakImageView;

    public BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask(ImageView imageView) {
        weakImageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        return ImageHelper.getBitmapFromURL(params[0]); //parameters are given in an array
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (weakImageView != null) {
            ImageView imageView = weakImageView.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                /*int bgColor = Palette.from(bitmap).generate().getDarkVibrantColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(App.getAppComponent().getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.black));

                bgLayout.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);*/
            }
        }
    }
}

static class DownloadDrawable extends ColorDrawable { //can we change this to a Bitmap Drawable
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask> weakBitmapAsyncTask;

    public DownloadDrawable(BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask task) {
        super(Color.LTGRAY);
        weakBitmapAsyncTask = new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask>(task);
    }

    public BitmapDownloaderAsyncTask getBitmapDownloadTask() {
        return weakBitmapAsyncTask.get();
    }
}
```

}

NewsActivity

```
public class NewsActivity extends BaseActivity implements NewsView{
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

private static NewsPresenterComponent newsPresenterComponent;

@Inject NewsPresenter presenter;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
NewsAdapter adapter;

List<Article> articles;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    implementComponents();

    articles = presenter.queryNews("world", 20);

    initializeRecyclerView();

}

public void implementComponents() {
    newsPresenterComponent = DaggerNewsPresenterComponent.builder()
            .newsPresenterModule(new NewsPresenterModule(this, this)) //this can be removed
            .build();
    newsPresenterComponent.inject(this);
}

private void initializeRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, articles);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void updateNewsAdapter() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to cache the images (e.g. write them to your internal/external memory). Then do the check if it exists -> read it from there, otherwise download it

Answer (score -1):

Just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which has built-in caching, placeholder image and many other things. You can replace your whole `ImageDownloader` class with just a one line.